# To contact moderator who responded for flag

Tags: discussion, support, flagging, moderators

Suppose I have raised a flag and moderator has responded for that flag, accepted/declined it.

I am happy/not happy with their decision and would like to thank/explain the point to the moderator who responded for my flag.

Is there any way to do that?

I guess one problem is that there might be a very long discussion between the person who raised the flag and the moderator who responded (which might irritate the moderator). But otherwise, I do not see any problem and I think it is a good practice to do.

Do we have such opportunity?

I am not asking to reveal the identity of the moderator. It is not about the person but about the work.

Comment: In general, you can write moderators@mathoverflow.net. In this case, I am almost certain you are referring to an action recently performed by me: if you don't have my personal email, I may be able to write you, with your permission, and you can tell me what's up. (Although, I don't encourage general users to reach me this way.)

Comment: Martin Sleziak pointed out another possibility which honestly hadn't occurred to me (probably because I usually avoid chat rooms): I can open up a private chat room for us to discuss what's on your mind. Maybe I'll try that.

Comment: @ToddTrimble i have nothing serious to ask.. I just wanted to say thanks for your action and wanted to ask if it is deleted permanently... Main reason is about my recent flag but in general also I want to ask if there is any way... How do I know that the same one who responded for my flag would respond to mail I have send to moderators@mathiverflow.com you do have a list who has responded to which flag???

Comment: With regard to the action, let's talk privately. But in general, it's easy for us moderators to determine who did what. Of course there is no guarantee that a moderator will respond in email.

Comment: "it's easy for us moderators to determine who did what." That would be great +1.. For every one else who is wondering if there is any problem with flag I raised, I want to say clearly that **there is no problem at all**.. :-) This question was just out of **curiosity to know how flags work**... **Nothing serious at all**...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, one can always write moderators@mathoverflow.net. From my own point of view, that would be the preferred option.

If it's something quick, a user can raise a second flag. I've seen this done when a user felt that a prior message in a flag hadn't gotten through or was misunderstood.

A third option is a private chat room, as mentioned in a comment. But that's something initiated only on the moderator end. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143645/278664

Comment: This more or less answers my question... :-)